# Import the VM image using the AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-ami

I'm trying to import my OVA image from my s3 bucket using the AWS CLI. I have

`aws ec2 import-image --disk-containers Format=ova,UserBucket="{S3Bucket=arn:aws:s3:::my-vm-rony,"S3Key=windows_7.ova}"`

I'm getting the following message:

> "An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage
>   operation: User does not have access to the S3 object"

My AWS user have the following permission:
AmazonS3FullAccess,
AdministratorAccess, AWSImportExportFullAccess, VMImportExportRoleForAWSConnector, AWSImportExportReadOnlyAccess, vmimport

I added to my bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1476979061000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::109816374014:user/RonyLevi"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-vm-rony",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-vm-rony/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a bucket name, not ARN:

```
aws ec2 import-image --disk-containers Format=ova,UserBucket="{S3Bucket=my-vm-rony,S3Key=windows_7.ova}"
```

Comment: If I'm writing only bucket name, I got **"An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: The given S3 object is not local to the region"**

Comment: From the docs: The bucket must be in the Region where you want to import your VMs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html Make sure your S3 bucket is in the same region where you are planning to restore your image. Also, you might need to use --region parameter for awc cli.